# can't cast to implemented interface

Tags: java, inheritance, classcastexception

i'm very confused...

I have a class which directly implements an interface:

```
public class Device implements AutocompleteResult
{...}
```

Here is proof that I'm looking at the right variables:

```
Object match = ...;
log.debug(match.getClass()); // Outputs 'Device'
log.debug(match.getClass().getInterfaces()[0]); // Outputs 'AutocompleteResult'
```

Yet when I try to cast an instance of the class to the interface:

```
AutocompleteResult result = (AutocompleteResult) match;
```

I get a ClassCastException!

```
ClassCastException: Device cannot be cast to AutocompleteResult
```

Also, `isAssignableFrom` returns false and i'm not sure why:

```
log.debug(AutocompleteResult.class.isAssignableFrom(Device.class));
```

from the [doc](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#isAssignableFrom%28java.lang.Class%29):

> **Determines if the** class or **interface represented by this Class object is** either the same as, or is a superclass or **superinterface of, the class or interface represented by the specified Class parameter.**

Shouldn't I always be able to cast a object to an interface its class implements?

Thanks.

Comment: Yes, you should! (and you shouldn't even need the explicit cast.)  Please post some self-contained example code that demonstrates the problem.

Answer (score 74, accepted):

This can happen if two different classloaders load a class named `AutocompleteResult`.

These two classes are then treated as *entirely different* classes, even if they have the same package and name (and even implementation/fields/methods).

A common cause for this is if you use some kind of plugin system and both your base classes and the plugin classes *provide* the same class.

To check for this issue print the value returned by [`Class.getClassLoader()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getClassLoader%28%29) on both offending classes (i.e. the class of the interface implemented by `Device` *and* the result of `AutocompleteResult.class`).

Comment: wow, thanks! i was literally tearing hair out on this one. i will try to resolve the classloading issue now...

Comment: +1: Try `log.debug(match.getClass().getInterfaces()[0].getClassLoader()); log.debug(AutocompleteResult.class.getClassLoader())`

Comment: My issue was that i had the wrong imported class and this helped me determine that : `Class[] interfaces = match.getClass().getInterfaces(); for(int i = 0; i < interfaces.length; i++){ Log.d(DEBUG_TAG, interfaces[i].toString()); Log.d(DEBUG_TAG, AutocompleteResult.class.toString()); } `

Answer (score 1):

AKA when Java apparently doesn't Java.

I hit this problem recently with Play Framework 2.6.3, what helped me was this:
https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/ThreadPools#Application-class-loader

I leave this info here for the people that might have the same problem.

To make it clearer, what helps is:

Injecting Application on an Eager Singleton and then using its classloader to load the classes I was having issues with.

To make it clearer

```
public class Module {


 @Override
 public void configure {
   bind(TheClassLoaderLoader.class).asEagerSingleton()

public static class TheClassLoaderLoader {
  @Inject
        public TheClassLoaderLoader( Application application) {

         ClassLoader classloader = application.classloader();

                Class<?> interfaceClass = classloader.loadClass(InterfaceClass.class.getName());
                classloader.loadClass(ImplementsInterfaceClass.class.getName()).asSubclass(interfaceClass);
```

The example here https://playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/JavaDependencyInjection#Configurable-bindings

That uses `Environment` often throws a frustrating `ClassNotFoundException`

Cheers