# ClassCastException: can't make an instance of Interface

Tags: java, classcastexception

```
package test;
public interface Virtual {
    String get();
}


package test;
public class Test implements Virtual {

    static { System.out.println("hello"); }
    public Test() { System.out.println("world"); }

    @Override
    public String get() {
        return "Test clazz";
    }
}

//main method
...
Class<?> cls = Class.forName("test.Test", true, classLoader); // it prints "hello"
Virtual instance = (Virtual) cls.newInstance(); 
// this gets ClassCastException: test.Test cannot be cast to test.Virtual
```

The idea is get Virtual instance which is Test implementation. 
What is wrong with this scenario?

update:
Finally I got it. It seems there was an eror in test.get().

Comment: If you remove your cast in `Virtual instance = (Virtual) cls.newInstance();` to be just `Virtual instance = cls.newInstance();` do you still get error?

Comment: This could help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12383376/classcastexception-when-casting-class-forname-object-to-interface-implemented-by

Comment: @CaptainMan in this case it will not compile because of `Type mismatch: cannot convert from capture#2-of ? to Virtual`. But I can get just Object instance.

Comment: Basically it could happen when Test is loaded by another class loader then Virtual.  Try pass `Virtual.class.getClassLoader()` as classloader

Comment: @AndriiLiubimov test.Test was compiled from a source file and in this case I get `ClassNotFoundException: test.Test`

Comment: Virtual instance = (Virtual) (cls.newInstance()); // cls is of Class<?> and cannot be casted to Virtual.

Comment: @PhyrumTea If you wanted to cast `cls` you'd do `((Virtual) cls).newInstance()`.

Comment: @Bubletan I wasn't sure if method call has higher precedence level than casting.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing cast `(Virtual)` Type and replace it with `Test`:

```
Virtual instance = (Virtual) cls.newInstance();
```

Change this to:

```
Virtual instance = Test.class.cast(cls.newInstance());
```

You cannot create an instance of `Virtual` as it is interface. However you can assign an instance of `Test` class to a reference variable which is of `Virtual` Type.

Comment: It can not be done because of `Test cannot be resolved to a type` because it was compiled from a source file.

Comment: I have updated my answer. If it does not work can you please post more details in your original question. e.g original question does not say source file is not present.