# ClassCastException from a List of objects which implement a common interface

Tags: java, interface, casting, osgi, classcastexception

I have a List of classes that implement the `IApplication` interface:

```
public interface IApplication {
    public void start();
}
public class Configurator implements IApplication {
    public void start() {...};
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<IApplication> apps = new ArrayList<IApplication>();
    apps.add(new Configurator());

    apps.get(0).start(); //ClassCastException   
}
```

When the last line in my Main function is executed, I get a `ClassCastException`:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: Configurator cannot be cast to IApplication
```

Even if I instantiate a Configurator object as an IApplication, I get the the following error:

```
IApplication app = new Configurator();
app.start();

java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Class Configurator does not implement the requested interface IApplication
```

Should this not be allowed in Java? Could it be an issue where my Configuration class is not getting updated correctly with the implementation?ClassCastException from a List of objects which implement a common interface

Comment: IApplication vs. Application? Is that intended?

Comment: @DirkLachowski no it wasn't. Fixed now

Comment: Did you forget to recompile Configurator after you made it implement IApplication?

Comment: @immibis No, I ensured that I recompiled and re-deployed Configurator. I am using OSGi so perhaps there is an issue going on behind the scenes?

Comment: possible duplicate of [can't cast to implemented interface](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8035877/cant-cast-to-implemented-interface)

Comment: What does `System.out.println(Arrays.toString(Configurator.class.getInterfaces())` print? What about `System.out.println(Arrays.asList(Configurator.class.getInterfaces()).stream().map(Class::getClassLoader).collect(Collectors.toList())+" "+IApplication.class.getClassLoader())`?

Comment: @immibis that output gives me:
`[interface com.common.IApplicationConfigurator]`
&&
`[Class Provider for bundle with BSN: com.configurator-plugin] Class Provider for bundle with BSN: com.configuration-management-common`

Comment: The output of this is `null`:
System.out.println( apps.getClass().getInterfaces()[0].getClassLoader());

Comment: There's nothing wrong here. Please provide the block of code in the `start()` method implementation.

Also, I'd fall back on the comment above about re-compiling, the error message does not jive:

`java.lang.ClassCastException: Configurator cannot be cast to Application`

Why would it try to cast to something called "Application" when it is an iApplication?

Comment: Try fully qualifying the class names with the package and see what happens.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to have two different interfaces loaded from different bundles, both named `IApplication`. In OSGI, classes (and interfaces, and enums, and so on) from different bundles are always distinct, even if they have the same name and package name!

`Configurator` implements the `IApplication` interface from the bundle `com.configurator-plugin`, whereas your `main` method is referring to the `IApplication` interface from the bundle `com.configuration-management-common`.

If they're supposed to be the *same* interface, you should remove it from one of those bundles, and make sure it's exported from the other, and make sure the bundle that exports the interface is a dependency of the bundle that uses it.

There's no simple way to specify which bundle to load a class or interfaces from, since the Java language has no concept of bundles to start with. If they're supposed to be two different interfaces, I suggest you make sure they have different names (and then the problem should be clear).