# A dozer map exception related to Spring boot devtools

Tags: java, spring-boot, classloader, dozer

I have encountered a very strange exception, and I don't know how to find the reason.

Business background:
Add goods and meantime it's price list, a goods have 5 price for diff level user.

In controller, first convert goodForm to goods by using dozer, then call goodsService to save goods.
In goodsService after saving goods, traversal goods price list and populate goodsId to goods price,

```
GoodsForm:
@Mapping("priceList")
List<GoodsPriceForm> goodsPriceFormList;
Goods:
List<GoodsPrice> priceList;

Controller: 
Goods goods = BeanMapper.map(goodsForm, Goods.class);
goodsService.saveGoods(adminId, goods);

GoodsService:
goodsDao.save(goods);
goods.getPriceList().forEach(p -> p.setGoodsId(goods.getId()));
goodsPriceDao.save(goods.getPriceList());
```

But it throw exception:

```
2015-11-27 17:10:57,042 [http-nio-8081-exec-8] ERROR o.a.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/].[dispatcherServlet] - Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.ClassCastException: com.foo.goods.model.GoodsPrice cannot be cast to com.foo.goods.model.GoodsPrice] with root cause
java.lang.ClassCastException: com.foo.goods.model.GoodsPrice cannot be cast to com.foo.goods.model.GoodsPrice
at com.foo.goods.service.GoodsService$$Lambda$11/310447431.accept(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
at java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1249) ~[na:1.8.0_51]
at com.foo.goods.service.GoodsService.saveGoods(GoodsService.java:34) ~[classes/:na]
```

This error message let me feel very confused.  In addition I write a unit test wanted to repeat this, but failed.

```
GoodsForm form = new GoodsForm();
form.setGoodsPriceFormList(Lists.newArrayList(new GoodsPriceForm((byte) 1, BigDecimal.valueOf(10)),
new GoodsPriceForm((byte) 2, BigDecimal.valueOf(9)),
new GoodsPriceForm((byte) 3, BigDecimal.valueOf(8))));

Goods goods = BeanMapper.map(form, Goods.class);
goods.getPriceList().forEach(p -> p.setGoodsId(goods.getId()));
```

Run this unit test, it executed ok. 
So why in real web situation(Spring boot + Jpa) it's failed, but in unit test situation it's ok?

---

```
Controller:
System.out.println("PriceList: " + goods.getPriceList().getClass().getClassLoader());//PriceList: null
System.out.println(goods.getPriceList().get(0).getClass().getClassLoader()); //java.lang.ClassCastException: com.foo.goods.model.GoodsPrice cannot be cast to com.foo.goods.model.GoodsPrice
```

---

If I generated a packaged jar, then execute this jar

```
java -jar target/myapp.jar
```

In this case without above exception.

---

And I commented spring-boot-devtools in pom.xml, then started application, without above exception.

Comment: The only time I have had an exception like that is if you load the same class with 2 different class loaders. Can you try printing out the class loader of each object?

Comment: Then the same class was loaded by two different class loaders. First measure is to have the class in just one jar at one location.

Comment: @Wim Deblauwe I have tried your way, please see my supplemental content at bottom of this post

Comment: So the goods.getPriceList already contains the wrong typed objects. Which might be the case (type erasure) with bean manipulating tools (**dozer**?). They maybe use another jar/class with same name. Dozer might be used be the web server, and have an other ClassLoader. BTW `BigDecimal.valueOf("9.00")` might be better: the precision then is 2 digits. `getClass().getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation().toString()` could tell the jar, when you would not get that error.

Comment: @Joop Eggen  In debug mode, I successed output the classloader, goodsPrice: sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@14dad5dc, goods: org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.classloader.RestartClassLoader@591c6338

Comment: No static price list? No price list kept longer than the application's life? Better loaded at application's start.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [can't cast to implemented interface](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8035877/cant-cast-to-implemented-interface)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> By default, any open project in your IDE will be loaded using the “restart” classloader, and any regular .jar file will be loaded using the “base” classloader. If you work on a multi-module project, and not each module is imported into your IDE, you may need to customize things. To do this you can create a META-INF/spring-devtools.properties file.
>
> The spring-devtools.properties file can contain restart.exclude. and restart.include. prefixed properties. The include elements are items that should be pulled-up into the “restart” classloader, and the exclude elements are items that should be pushed down into the “base” classloader. The value of the property is a regex pattern that will be applied to the classpath.

My Solution: put `META-INF/spring-devtools.properties` inside resources folder, and add this content

```
restart.include.dozer=/dozer-5.5.1.jar
```

Please see : http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#using-boot-devtools-customizing-classload

Comment: If you use dozer-spring, add this too :  
restart.include.dozer-spring=/dozer-spring-5.5.1.jar

Comment: This file also supports regexp paths, so I'd rather use `restart.include.dozer=/dozer-[\\w\\d.]+\\.jar` instead. It's easy to forget to update this property when updating dependency.

Answer (score 1):

You are using two different `ClassLoader` here. An identical `Class` loaded with two different `ClassLoader` is considered as two **different** `Class` by the JVM.

The solution to fix this is simple : Use an `Interface`.

Interfaces are able to abstract this problem, and you can interchange the object they implement between ClassLoaders without limitation, as long as you don't reference the implementation directly.

Comment: I go with you on the first part, but your second part is totally wrong. An interface is, from the view of a class loader, a class file as well. So `classLoader1.loadClass("...MyInterface") != classLoader2.loadClass("...MyInterface")`.

Comment: Oh you are right, I didn't mean it that way, but it totally came out that way. I just edited my wording to make it clearer.

Comment: I think this is still vague. If you read my duplication mark on the OP you will see, that this was about an interface. As long as you still load the interface with the two different classloaders, you will have no benefit from using an interface. I know that there are situations where an interface or superclass from the _common parent class loader_ will help, but I don't think that the current question belongs to one of that situations. You can still prove me wrong with an example...