# dozer mapper error while mapping abstract types

Tags: dozer

I have two hierarchy of inheritance that needs to get mapped. one hierarchy is domestic and the other is wild. I have abstract DomesticAnimal and concrete DomesticCat and DomesticDog extending it. In the second hierarchy, I have abstract WildAnimal and concrete WildCat and WildDog extending it. I have two more classes which are WildAnimalFeederhaving member object of WildAnimal  and DomesticAnimalFeeder having member object of DomesticAnimal. considering the field names are identical in both hierarchies, what would be a correct dozer mapping of it? I will soon attach dozer configuration that I have tried and failed.

Comment: I have found the problem was due to spring-devtools as mentioned [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33955542/a-dozer-map-exception-related-to-spring-boot-devtools)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The resolution was adding a resource/META-INF/spring-devtools.properties with following lines
restart.include.dozer=/dozer-5.5.1.jar.

spring boot dev was causing the classes to be mapped to be loaded twice.